# cocos2d-xでUnityのようなInput関数をつくりたいです。

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

cocos2d-x 3.10を使用してゲームの作成を行っている、学生です。

cocos2d-xのEventListenerKeyboardでリスナーを作って、
onKeyPressedに事前に関数を入れておくというやり方ではなく、

Unityのような、bool Input::GetKeyDown(KeyCode keyCode)などの、
押された、押されている、離したのを判定する関数を実装したいのですが、

どういう実装をしたらよいか思いつきません。

もしよろしければ、ご回答よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

[Cocos](http://jp.cocos.com/learn/)[ドキュメント](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/docs/programmers-guide/8/index.html)によると、`EventListenerKeyboard`というリスナーを使用すると、キーボードのイベントを判定することが出来るようです。

[もとのコード例によると](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/docs/programmers-guide/8/index.html#creating-a-keyboard-event)、`EventListenerKeyboard::create()`という行をまず使って、それから`onKeyPressed`とか`onKeyReleased`とかの関数を通して、キーボードのエベントなどをキャッチすることが出来ると思いますね。